# Issue with adding a not null columns to an existing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-migrations

I have problem with adding not nullable columns to a table.
I read many posts about this and it should be correct.

Migration code:

```
  def change
    add_column :individual_trainings, :start_on, :time
    add_column :individual_trainings, :end_on, :time

    change_column_null :individual_trainings, :start_on, false
    change_column_null :individual_trainings, :end_on, false
  end
```

Error:

```
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  column "start_on" contains null values...
```

I don't have any idea why isn't working. How should I correct write change method?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
It was my big fault. I was have one record in this table... I cleared table and  migrate. Now it's working. Sorry for my stupidity and waste of your time.

Comment: I don't know exactly your case, but you can use this `add_column :individual_trainings, :start_on, :time, default: false ` and try if it works

Comment: I recently wrote a migration to do exactly what you did. But in my case, I had deleted all of records with null values. Because from now, our database should not accept null values. Can you remove this records with null values or not?

Comment: @AdrianoTadao I don't have any records in this table.

Comment: have you tried something like this? `change_column :individual_trainings, :start_on, :datetime, null: false`

Is very strange if you don't have any records. Are you sure about this? Could you check out via [postico](https://eggerapps.at/postico/) or psql ? Maybe you have some hidden record, I don't know. xD

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your migration would have worked if there would not be any record in your `individual_trainings` table.

Since you have records in your table,when you add the `start_on` column, immediately the column values gets set to `null` and then you impose the `NOT NULL` constraint on it. That's why you are getting this error.

**Solution:**

Just set a default value(except null) while adding the `start_on` or `end_on` columns and then go ahead with the migration to enforce `NOT NULL` constraint.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is because you are saying that `:start_on`cannot be `null` with this ([explaination here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_null)):

`change_column_null :individual_trainings, :start_on, false`

but you are leaving it `null`

Add a default value when creating the column and will be fine:

```
add_column :individual_trainings, :start_on, :time, default: false
```

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
 def change
   change_column_default :individual_trainings, :start_on, Time.now
   change_column_default :individual_trainings, :end_on, Time.now
 end
```

For More details see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_default

And To set not null contraint do this

```
def change
  change_column :individual_trainings, :start_on, :time, :null => false
  change_column :individual_trainings, :end_on, :time, :null => false
end
```

Comment: If I try your suggestion I have this error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type time: "f"
: ALTER TABLE "individual_trainings" ALTER COLUMN "start_on" SET DEFAULT 'f'

Comment: Its because of `time` type, you used `time` datatype for this.  So you have to set `current date`  as default value. see updated code.

Comment: Not exactly, because I wanted set not null for columns, not default value.

Comment: Yes, default value is another thing. Is very strange your error. @ŁukaszKorol let us know how you solved this problem, please.

Comment: It was my big fault. I was have one record in this table... I cleared table and  migrate. Now it's working.